# Tests for independence in ragged arrays / bipartite matchings

Tags: categorical-data, independence, graph-theory, hypergeometric-distribution

Let $(Y_i, K_i)$, $i=1,\dotsc,N$ be pairs of observations drawn from discrete labels $L$ and discrete clusters IDs $C$.

For example $Y$ could be individual birds, $L$ could be a set of species and $C$ could be the location of bird feeders where the birds are observed.  (In this contrived example assume the birds may only visit one feeder.)

```
|species(Y)   |feeder(K) |
|:------------|:---------|
|chickadee    |A         |
|starling     |A         |
|crow         |A         |
|chickadee    |B         |
|chickadee    |B         |
|crow         |C         |
|crow         |C         |
```

We are interested if $Y \perp K$ conditional on both the number and size of the clusters.  One method to test this would be to permute $Y$, and calculate some statistic and estimate the tail probability of the statistic under permutation.  Let $\left(\tilde{Y}_i, \tilde{K}_i \right)$ be such as permutation.  Then one statistic we might consider is $S\left(\tilde{Y}_i, \tilde{K}_i \right)$, the number of clusters comprised of purely a single species, find its distribution under independence by repeated permutation and then compare to an observed value.

### Questions:

1. Is there a more powerful test for independence than $S\left(Y_i, K_i \right)$?  My intuition that some sort of studentization would lead to a superior test.  Is there a way to cast this a GLM somehow?
2. Is there a way to adjust for a covariate, that is, test if $Y \perp K | X$?  A naive approach would be to calculate $S$, and permute only within each level of $X$. This would only seem to work when $X$ is discrete and seems hopelessly inefficient when $X$ is sparse.

### Edit: A contingency table formulation

Note this forms a bipartite graph between colored vertices Y and uncolored K, or assuming an IID distribution within each cluster and label pair, we could summarize the data as a $L \times C$ contingency table:
$$
\begin{array}[lccc]
N & \text{chickadee} & \text{crow} & \text{starling} \\
A & 1 & 1 & 1\\
B & 2 & 0  & 0  \\
C & 0  &2 & 0
\end{array}
$$
When written like this, Fisher's exact test for 2-way ($>2\times 2$) tables is now gazing suspiciously in my direction.